# Doing a + between 2 column of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i do a sum of 2 column in the same table? What is the correct sql to do a plus

Example:
 
I have 2 column on the same table: currentcharges & overduecharge
I need to do a statement currentcharge + overduecharge.

Comment: Why not try it first?

Comment: With simple operations, it is much quicker to try it yourself. Then post here if it *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select currentcharge + overduecharge as total_charge from the_table
```

The alias ("total_charge") is optional, but helpful if you need to refer to the computed column later.